# When i click a button i would like to activate only its surrounding buttons. How is this possible?

Tags: java, android, button, logic, android-button

I have an 8 by 8 linear Layout of buttons. I am making a small game similar to boggle, when i click a button i would like to be able to disable all buttons except for its surrounding buttons. This also involves the buttons on the edge. I basically need some help to start the logic of this game. any help is appreciated. i have so far thought about the structure of the program and how an 8 by 8 graph can possibly activate its neighbors, maybe if i can access the cell of each button the i can progress further?. Thank you.

Comment: I think if I were trying this, I'd have a two dimensional array of buttons that all called back to the same controller that handled the logic of enabling/disabling the buttons as the game state changed.  I'm not familiar with boggle, but that's probably the way I'd try to approach what you're doing.

Comment: ALSO:  
Try this link, it's a java implementation of boggle: http://www.gtoal.com/wordgames/duke_boggle/joggle/

Answer (score 1):

Extend Button and give Buttonlisteners to each of the buttons according to who their neighbors are. Each button would have a buttonlistener tied to each of it's neighbors according to how you tie it together. If you don't want to use diagonal neighbors, a button would have a max of 5 buttonlisteners (if the button is listening to it's own button).)

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible to accomplish using a simple Map:

```
Map<Button, List<Button>> surroundingButtons = new HashMap<Button, List<Button>>();
```

This Map is then, for each Button, populated with a list of it's surrounding Buttons. Unfortunately I have no clever idea how to do this easily at this hour.
I am thinking something like adding all buttons to a single list and pick them out using index of the current button +/- 8 modulo some index... Adding them manually might be just as easy.

When the Map is ready, it is very simple to disable the surrounding Buttons.

```
Button clickedButton; // not showing the onClickListener
for (Button sButton: surroundingButtons.get(clickedButton)) {
    sButton.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Edit:

Read the question wrong but;  *disable all buttons **except** for its surrounding buttons*
The idea still applies, just add all the buttons you wish to disable to the list associated with a button in the map.